# Get data from rdf file

Tags: java, file-io, rdf, jena, ontology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Using Jena APi - Get data from RDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915865/java-using-jena-api-get-data-from-rdf-file)

I'm using Java and Jena API.

I have the class `Person` with the datatype properties `hasFirstName`, `hasLastName`, `hasDateOfBirth`, `hasGender`.

Here is how one person is represented in my RDF file.

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.fam.com/FAM#Bruno04/02/1980 ">
    <j.0:FAMhasGender>H</j.0:FAMhasGender>
    <j.0:FAMhasDateOfBirth>04/02/1980</j.0:FAMhasDateOfBirth>
    <j.0:FAMhasLastName>DS </j.0:FAMhasLastName>
    <j.0:FAMhasFirstName> Bruno</j.0:FAMhasFirstName>
 </rdf:Description>
```

I'd like to get for each person the firstname, gender, date of birth and write that information in a text file. The problem I have is that it only writes the first woman/man he finds in the rdf file, but there is more than one woman and man.

Can you please explain me how can I solve this?
Thank you very much.

```
ExtendedIterator instances = onto.person.listInstances();
Individual instance = null;
Individual firstInstance = null;
while (instances.hasNext()) {
    instance = (Individual) instances.next();

    gen = instance.getPropertyValue(onto.hasGender).toString();
    fname = instance.getPropertyValue(onto.hasFirstName).toString();
    dd = instance.getPropertyValue(onto.hasDateOfBirth).toString();

    writeFile(fname, dd, genr);}


// Write text file
public void writeFile(String fn, String dbir, String gn) {
    String fileout = "D:/file1.txt";
    String firstName = fn;
    String dateB = dbir;
    String gender = gn;

    BufferedWriter out;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileout, true));

        if (gender.equals("F")) {
            out.write("[label= \"" + firstName + " \"\n\n\"D.Naiss:" + dnai1 + "\", " + shape + "]");
        } else if (gender.equals("M")) {
            out.write("[label= \"" + firstName + " \"\n\n\"D.Naiss:" + dnai1 + "\", " + shape2 + "]");
        }

        out.newLine();

        // flushes and closes the stream
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem:" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that?! An exact copy of your previous question that I answered with a different title?! See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915865/java-output-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Jena or RDF but is rather a logic error in your coding.

You call `writeFile()` inside your while loop which opens a new file, writes the current entry and closes the file.  So you are repeatedly overwriting your file with a single entry at one time so you will only ever end up with a single person in the file.

You need to refactor the code to open the file once before the while loop, have the `writeFile()` method simply add to that file (and not close it) and then close the file after the while loop.

Also as @Udo Kilmaschewski pointed out in your apparent duplicate the `genr` variable is not defined in the code you showed so you don't appear to be correctly passing the gender from your while loop to the `writeFile()` function.

Comment: `new FileWriter(fileout, true)` appends to the file.

Comment: Oops, my mistake but the basic principal still holds - unless the calculation in the loop is expensive (and as a Jena developer I can tell you it isn't) it's odd to close and reopen the file on every iteration through the loop

Comment: Exactly, that isn't the way to code optimal.